# Preserving formatting when copying and pasting in MS Word10

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm a writer. I am copying chapters and pasting them into a master file. I have the reveal formatting button on and all looks the same in both documents. But sometimes (1 out of 10 times) when I copy a chapter and paste it into the master, the fonts, shadowing and paragraph formatting change when I paste.I have only a "homeowner's" knowledge of computer terminology.

Comment: Revealing formatting has nothing do with actual styling. Try to trace what changes in that 1 out of 10 case when you paste. Maybe some text piece differs from others? The default behavior is preserving the formatting, so this 10% is an exception, that as its cause.

Comment: What's changing in pasted text is: (1) font (from Garamound 14 to Times Roman 14); (2) indentations are lost; (3) text is shadowed

Comment: Check [this settings](http://10629-presscdn-0-58.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/pictures/2010/10/05_keep_text_only_for_four_pasting_options.png) in Word ([how](http://helpdeskgeek.com/office-tips/always-paste-text-into-word-2010-from-an-outside-source-without-formatting/)). What Word version do you have? You paste from external program or from another word doc?

Comment: Word10. I'm doing everything within Word. I have both files open. Copy one and paste into the other.

Comment: Can you show an image of the original text and how it pastes in the master?

Answer (score -1):

In Word there are two kinds of formatting, there is "Character" and "Paragraph" formatting (there is a third kind kind managed by section jumps, that is page formatting, but I don't think here it's the case).

When you copy a section of text, you could be selecting only characters or the whole paragraph. If you select only characters, the paragraph formatting will not be copied. If you use the "Show hidden characters [image]" you'll see the paragraph marks.

Here you select only Characters:
[image: Char Select]

Here you Select the whole paragraph:
[image: Paragraph Select]

So, in the second case, the paragraph formatting (line spacing, justify, etc.) will be copied.

Comment: Is this a clue? When I copy and paste into a blank page, it comes out exactly as the original. But (sometimes) when I copy (Select All + copy) and paste into the main file I'm creating, I get the changes I described above.

Comment: @IdrianResnick I think you have made changes in the styles, so when you paste into the main document your text takes style from the main. You have to check the options on paste, you have to option to keep the formatting of the source or apply the formatting of the document where you are pasting it.

Comment: No @fernando.reyes. I tried that, using both paste options = keep text only, and merge formatting. In a new document both options alter the paragraph indentations but keep the font/pt and non-bolding. When I do that and paste in the Master file, the changes I mentioned above occur. So I think there is something in the Master file that's changing what's pasted. How can I find that and get rid of it? And why does it only occur with some pastes and not others?

Comment: I solved it. I followed the suggestion and went to "Change Styles" tab and edited the default setting for "default" and "Normal", then saved and reloaded by file and badabing badaboom! Thanks, people!

Comment: @IdrianResnick Great this helped in some way, good luck with your book